# Turning a java method into HTTP request

Tags: java, json, gson

I'd like to turn the following java method into a request to use with a debugger (Fiddler / Postman).
The java app is using gson, I don't know if it is relevant tho.

```java
public static boolean openTest() throws URISyntaxException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    HttpGetWithEntity request = new HttpGetWithEntity();
    request.setURI(new URI(baseURL));
    JsonObject loginBase = new JsonObject();
    loginBase.addProperty("action", "testing");
    loginBase.addProperty("age", age_string);
    loginBase.addProperty("height", height_string);
    request.setEntity((HttpEntity)new StringEntity(loginBase.toString()));
}
```

I figured it should look something like this:

```
{"action":"testing","age":"age_string","height":"height_string"}
```

But when trying this on the debugger, the response is blank with status 200.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your endpoint and what should it return?

Comment: @tomerpacific I don't exactly know what it is supposed to return but the endpoint is:
    try {
      CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute((HttpUriRequest)request);
      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
      successfulLogin = result.contains("accept");
      return successfulLogin;

Comment: the endpoint is the url part and I cannot see what it is if it is inside your url request. If you paste that url in the browser, what do you get?

Comment: I get "Generic Server Heroku Status Running"
This connects to a server (the URL is an IP adress).